# Difficulty in resolving union query

Tags: ms-access

I have 2 tables:

S_tbl

```
====================
id | barcode | qty |
====================
1 | 1234     | 10  |
1 | 111      | 5   |
1 | 1234     | 10  |
```

K_tbl

```
=============================
id | barcode | qty | newQty |
=============================
1  | 1234    | 10  | 20     |
```

I run this query:

```
SELECT K_Tbl.id, K_Tbl.barcode, K_Tbl.Qty, K_Tbl.NewQty
FROM   K_Tbl where K_Tbl.id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT S_Tbl.id, S_Tbl.barcode, S_Tbl.Qty, '0' as NewQty
FROM   S_Tbl where S_Tbl.id = 1
```

and I get this:

```
=============================
id | barcode | qty | newQty |
=============================
1 | 1234      | 10 | 20     |
1 | 1234      | 10 | 20     |
1 | 1234      | 10 | 0      |
1 | 111       | 5  | 0      |
```

How to merge  same lines that the result will be like this:

```
=============================
id | barcode | qty | newQty |
=============================
1 | 1234     | 10  | 20     |
1 | 1234     | 10  | 20     |
1 | 111      | 5   | 0      |
```

**EDIT:**

i add the line: `1 | 1234     | 10  |`  to  **S_Tbl**

what i need to change in the query:

```
SELECT K_Tbl.id, K_Tbl.barcode, K_Tbl.Qty, K_Tbl.NewQty
FROM K_Tbl where K_Tbl.id = 1
UNION
SELECT S_Tbl.id, S_Tbl.barcode, S_Tbl.Qty, K_Tbl.NewQty
FROM S_Tbl 
left join K_Tbl on S_Tbl.id=K_Tbl.id and S_Tbl.barcode=K_Tbl.barcode
where S_Tbl.id = 1
```

that i'll see

```
=============================
id | barcode | qty | newQty |
=============================
1 | 1234     | 10  | 20     |
1 | 1234     | 10  | 20     |
1 | 111      | 5   | 0      |
```

Right now I see:

```
=============================
id | barcode | qty | newQty |
=============================
1 | 1234     | 10  | 20     |
1 | 111      | 5   | 0      |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT K_Tbl.id, K_Tbl.barcode, K_Tbl.Qty, K_Tbl.NewQty
FROM K_Tbl where K_Tbl.id = 1
UNION
SELECT S_Tbl.id, S_Tbl.barcode, S_Tbl.Qty, K_Tbl.NewQty
FROM S_Tbl 
left join K_Tbl on S_Tbl.id=K_Tbl.id and S_Tbl.barcode=K_Tbl.barcode
where S_Tbl.id = 1
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1793/2)**

I am sure this Query will work from **`MS-ACCES`**

Comment: @Gold **`SELECT S_Tbl.id, S_Tbl.barcode, S_Tbl.Qty, NZ(K_Tbl.NewQty,0) FROM S_Tbl left join K_Tbl on S_Tbl.id=K_Tbl.id and S_Tbl.barcode=K_Tbl.barcode where S_Tbl.id = 1`** [SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9ce6/1) For **sql server**

Comment: @Gold please verify the above Query and reply.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I get too many rows... i'll start new tidy Cluster

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION instead of UNION ALL - slower, but cares about the duplicates and removes them. Refer to MSDN doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208962(v=office.12).aspx

> By default, no duplicate records are returned when you use a UNION
>   operation; however, you can include the ALL predicate to ensure that
>   all records are returned. This also makes the query run faster.

And it is also same in Oracle or MSSQL.